# How do I connect an SDK to Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, leap-motion

I'm very new to SDK. I don't know how to add SDKs I downloaded to Visual Studio.

To be more specific, I've downloaded the SDK from LEAP MOTION for Windows:
https://developer.leapmotion.com/dashboard

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 and writting in C++.

I just want to know how to connect the SDK to VS, so I can use the methods provided by the
SDK.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the DLL Libraries into your code using the reference adding and the using or import reference (depending prog language). There are DLL for X86 and X64 arquitectures, select the full filled compliment version for your project and machine. When your code has no errors pleas, copy the DLL into the Release and Debug folder manually or you will have runtime exceptions.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There should be some documentation on the Leap Motion website, if it's compatible with Visual Studio. Also, check out this link, it might help: http://jviaches.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/leap-motion-development-connection-and.html